# How to convert a directory to a string?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have I `symlink` named `CURRENT` pointing to a directory , lets say

```
CURRENT -> $HOME/local/java/jdk1.8.0
```

I want to extract the `jdk1.8.0` part as a string.

First, I get the directory by :

```
 current_dir= $(readlink -f $CURRENT)
```

And then, I tried to extract the last part of the path :

```
last_part= ${current_dir##*/}
```

or even when I try to print it via :

```
echo $current_dir
```

I get this **error**:

```
bash: /home/tarrsalah/local/java/jdk1.8.0: Is a directory
```

How can I convert a directory to a string ?

Comment: Your errors occur due to the space following the equal sign: there must be **no** whitespace around the equal in shell variable assignment.

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman , I prefer using `basename` , less error prone.

Comment: ok, although my comment refers to a very fundamental aspect of shell programming which you appear to have trouble with.

Comment: yes, I can see, this is my first shell script :) ,I will pay attention for this case,  Thanks again.

Comment: Good, it seems very useful, thanks @thatotherguy

Comment: The actual problem is the space after the `=` signs in the code.  When you run: `current_dir= $(readlink -f $CURRENT)`, it first runs the `readlink` command, obtaining the pathname.  That output is then used as a command name, but the variable `current_dir` is set to empty in its environment before it is run.  Of course, since the name is actually a directory, `bash` reports '... is a directory'.  Do not put spaces around assignments in shells.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `basename`:

```
$ basename /home/tarrsalah/local/java/jdk1.8.0
jdk1.8.0
```